# Conversion from WCHAR to const unsigned char

Tags: c++, wix

I am a wix application packager. I am quite new to C++ and I am stuck with the below issue.

In my code, I am trying to convert `wchar` to `const unsigned char`. I have tried quite a few solutions that I got on the Internet, but I am unable to do it.

```cpp
WCHAR szabc[888] = L"Example";

const unsigned char* pText = (const unsigned char*)szabc;
```

For your reference, the value of `szabc` is hard-coded, but ideally it is fetched as user input during installation of my code. `szabc` needs to be converted to `const unsigned char` as `operator=` doesn't seem to be working for conversion.

I am not getting any compilation error, but when I run this code, only the first character of `szabc` is being assigned to `pText`, I want the whole value of `szabc` to be assigned to `pText`.

As the value of `pText` is a user account password in a real time scenario, and it will be passed to a method which encrypts the value of the password.

Answer (score 2):

Since you neglected to mention your OS, I am assuming it is Windows. You need [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) or the standard [wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/) functions.

Note that both will determine the target encoding using system settings, so results *will* vary across computers. If possible, convert to UTF-8 or tell your users to stay away from special characters.

Answer (score 1):

`operator=` cannot assign a value to a variable of an unrelated type.  Which is why you cannot assign a `WCHAR[]` directly to an `unsigned char*`.

However, the real problem is with how the pointed data is being *interpreted*. You have a 16-bit Unicode string, and you are trying to pass it to a method that clearly wants a null-terminated 8-bit string instead.

On Windows, `WCHAR` is 2 bytes, and so the 2nd *byte* in your Unicode string is `0x00`, eg:

```cpp
WCHAR szabc[] = {L'E', L'x', L'a', L'm', L'p', L'l', L'e', L'\0'};
```

Has the same memory layout as this:

```cpp
BYTE szabc[] = {'E', 0x00, 'x', 0x00, 'a', 0x00, 'm', 0x00, 'p', 0x00, 'l', 0x00, 'e', 0x00, '\0', 0x00};
```

This is why the method appears to see only 1 "character".  It stops reading when it encounters the 1st `0x00` byte.

Thus, a simple pointer type-cast will not suffice.  You will need to either:

- use an 8-bit string to begin with, eg:

  ```cpp
  CHAR szabc[888] = "Example";
  unsigned char* pText = (unsigned char*)szabc;
  // use pText as needed...
  ```
- *convert* the Unicode data at runtime, using [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) or equivalent, eg:

  ```cpp
  WCHAR szabc[888] = L"Example";
  int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, szabc, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  CHAR szConverted = new char[len];
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, szabc, -1, szConverted, len, NULL, NULL);
  unsigned char* pText = (unsigned char*)szConverted;
  // use pText as needed...
  delete[] szConverted;
  ```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, you literally saved me. I have been struggling with this since two days.

Comment: Much appreciated. :)